# In Excel, how'd I find values in column A missing from column B?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

In my Excel spreadsheet, lets say I have 2 columns, A and B. All values in B reside in A:

```
A     B
foo   foo
bar   baz
baz
quux
```

I want to filter column A to find values missing from B. In this case, the values returned should be `bar` and `quux`.

I tried using a combo of the `FILTER`, `MATCH`, and `ISNA` functions to no avail:

```
=FILTER(A:A, ISNA(MATCH(A:A, B:B, 0)))
```

Comment: I have also tried solutions throughout Google search results like: https://trumpexcel.com/compare-two-columns/
but many of these solutions assuming matching rows (and diff row-wise values).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check whether **the array formula** is helpful.

`=INDEX(A:A,SMALL(IF(COUNTIF(B$1:B$2,A$1:A$4)=0,ROW($1:$4),4^8),ROW(A1)))&""`

[image]

Comment: It looks like that works! This also works for me:

`
=FILTER(A:A,ISNA(MATCH(A:A,B:B,0)))
`